# I need help with Cahn-Ingold-Prelog (boat conformation)

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

[image]

I need to decide if the chiral carbon (with the attached hydrogen) is in R-configuration or S-configuration. To be able to do that, I need to know which of the atoms are pointing backward, forward and which are in planar. It looks like the molecule is in a boat conformation, but there is not clear drawing of which direction the atoms are pointing. Is there a specific rule when deciding which of the atoms on the chiral carbon is pointing backward, forward and which is in planar?

Thank you so much in advance! All answers are appreciated.

---

[image]

It's drawn like this in my workbook. If I'm not wrong; hydrogen is in the exo-position, but I don't know if that means it's pointing forward or backward. In chair conformations we usually have axial and equatorial positions. Does that apply to boat conformations too?

---

[image]

I tried drawing the molecule with help from the answers. Since hydrogen is in planar, I switch it with the atom pointing backwards. Based on the priorities of the atoms and their positions, this will give us R-configuration. However since we changed two positions the answer will be reversed and thus the chiral senter is S-configured. Does this sound correct?

Comment: In that case, see the left structure in my answer. The bond with the wedge is going back. It should be straightforward now.

Comment: As in hydrogen is pointing backwards? is there a spesific rule when it comes to boat conformations (e.g. equatorial vs axial positions in chair conformations)? Shouldn't there be two atoms in planar, one pointing back and one pointing forward? But in the drawing under there seems to be two pointing forward and two in planar.  I appreciate your answer, thank you.

Comment: Each carbon atom is tetrahedral. You treat it exactly the same way as if it weren't in a ring. The H and the C-C bond down are in plane. The C-N bond is wedge forward. The C-C bond of the ring is wedge back. Try building the structure if you're still confused.

Comment: I tried solving my question based on your answer in the official comment; does it look correct? :)

Comment: Welcome again! Unfortunately this is not really how Chemistry.se works. You can take the [tour] to find out more. The problem -- now -- is that the question and answer don't really go together. SE is not a forum, back-and-forth is discouraged as the system is not designed for it. We are rather looking for concise questions with concise answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually tell here because your drawing is abiguous. Where the bond going up from the nitrogen crosses the other bond, we need to know which one is in front. Usually, you show that by making a small break in the bond in the back and/or bolding the bonds that are in front.

Which one is it?

[image: Two alternatives]

Comment: When I look at the OP's structure, I invariably see it as your left hand structure. I have to concentrate to see it as the right hand one. How about you? Would make an interesting survey question.

Comment: I had a situation at work recently with a silhouette that felt similar, but in this case, I can see both just as easily.